# How to select entities and sum by frequency from a table? (specific)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, cout

I have a table with students that groups the language (language students are learning) and the grade they obtained in the given language. I need to extract the frequency of grades people are getting per language.

Example input:

```
id lang  grade
1. French A
2. Spanish A
3. French B
4. Spanish A 
5. French B
6. French C
```

Output (in table format)

```
French A 1 
French B 2 
French C 1 
Spanish A 2
```

it has to be a compact and dynamic query. Do you have any suggestions please? :)

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select lang, grade, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by lang, grade
```

Comment: Thank you! :) In the actual database it's a but more complicated and there are more grades, but I only need to extract the 3 most frequent grade, for each language group. Like : French A 14 French B 10 French C 6, Spanish A 23 Spanish B 21 Spanish C 32 and so on. Do you have a suggestion how to implement it? the simple limit function does not work.

Comment: @geek-o Use window function in CTE. PS. "First N rows in a group" is frequent question - searching will give a lot of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, i've found it, another thing, I have students with more than one grade in a language, but i would like to count those grades one by one. So there are several grade columns per student, but I would like to have one grade column. Ex. 1. French A B B (one row) => 1. French A 1. French B 1. French B  (3 rows)  It is a sort of join but I can't find how to make it within a table and not between tables. Do you have an idea how to do it?